# How do I animate video windows?

Tags: animation, video

I am looking to create a collage of 4 different windows all displaying their own individual video content simultaneously, each manifesting in the centre of the screen and then moving to one of four corners as the animation progresses. Is this possible in Blender? Thanks!

Comment: Blender can do that. You would use the Video Sequencer and Movie Clip Editor for that kind of stuff. Here is the documentation for those Editor screens: [Video Sequencer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/2.79/editors/vse/index.html) | [Movie Clip Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/2.79/editors/movie_clip_editor/index.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot PJM :D